# Cannot remove git refs/original

Tags: git

I have a bare repo I just cleaned out using the following

```
$ git filter-branch --index-filter \
               'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch junk/bigfile' -- --all
```

For a couple of files plus a folder. Attempting to remove second and third files gave me error

```
Cannot create new backup. A previous backup already exists in refs/original/
Force overwriting the backup with -f
```

So I attempted

```
$ git filter-branch -f --index-filter \
               'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch junk/bigfile' -- --all
```

for a second file and

```
$ git filter-branch --index-filter \
               'git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch Folder-I-Want-To-Remove' -- --all
```

for a folder I wanted to clean out. Now that I'm running

```
rm -rf refs/original
```

to attempt to shrink the repository back down I'm getting error

```
fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree
```

What should I do? I had planned to run through

```
$ rm -rf refs/original
$ git fsck
$ git prune
$ git gc
$ git repack -a
```

But I'm a bit nervous about doing that now since the first command errored out.

Thanks!

Comment: `rm` is not a Git command (note the lack of `git` in front). Are you sure you ran `rm -rf refs/original` and not `git rm -rf refs/original`? The latter *would* give you that error. (I'm not a fan of the `rm -rf refs/original` technique since it neglects the possibility of *packed* refs, but it should work right after a simple filter-branch.)

Comment: Which command was it that gave the `this operation must be run in a work tree` error? Is it `rm ...` or `git rm ...` or one of the other commands?

Comment: You might also consider using the newfangled [git filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/) instead of filter-branch. It's a bit harder to set up but it's overall more user friendly.

Comment: Yup, I definitely ran `git rm -rf refs/original` out of habit. So drop the `git` piece and I should be good I take it?